# Add text colour to a specific column name (header) in DT Shiny datatable

Tags: shiny, dt

I am fairly new to DT in Shiny and would like to add text colour to specific columns in a table, I can do this using `formatStyle` as per the below example code chunk. However, I would also like to add the same text colour to the corresponding column name (header), is there an easy way to do this?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui = fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput('fDataTable'))

server = function(input, output) {
  output$fDataTable = DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(iris) %>%
      formatStyle(columns = 1, color = "red") %>%
      formatStyle(columns = 3, color = "blue")
  })
}  

app = list(ui = ui, server = server)
runApp(app)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this by adding CSS to the `colnames` of the table you are rendering (you also need to set `escape` to `FALSE` or the html will be escaped).

Here's an example:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui = fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput('fDataTable'))

server = function(input, output) {
  output$fDataTable = DT::renderDataTable({
    iris_coloured <- iris
    colnames(iris_coloured)[c(1,3)] <- paste0('<span style="color:',c("red","blue"),'">',colnames(iris)[c(1,3)],'</span>')
    DT::datatable(iris_coloured,escape=F) %>%
      formatStyle(columns = 1, color = "red") %>%
      formatStyle(columns = 3, color = "blue")
  })
}  

app = list(ui = ui, server = server)
runApp(app)
```